# Bitcoin Core reports progress only up to 0.999999

Tags: bitcoin-core, synchronization, full-node

On older version - after full synchronization in debug log i see message
`progress=1.0` 
In new - only `progress=0.999999`, it`s normal or i have some problems with synchronization?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a rounding issue, and not new.

You are most likely fully synchronized.